# Is it possible to use Django ORM to select no table fields receiving only values calculated based on real columns?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

So the question is "is it possible to make the following query using Django ORM without raw statements?"

```
SELECT
 my_table.column_a + my_table.column_b
FROM
 my_table
```

**The example** for which it would be suitable from my point of view:

We have a model:

```
class MyOperations(models.Model):
    operation_start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

At some point we create a record and set the field value to `Now` (or we update some existing record. it doesn't matter):

```
MyOperations.objects.create(operation_start_time=functions.Now())
```

Now we want to know how much time has already passed. I would expect that Django ORM produces the following SQL statement to request data from the database (let's assume that we use MySQL backend):

```
SELECT
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, `myapp_myoperations`.`operation_start_time`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `time_spent`
FROM
 `myapp_myoperations`
WHERE ...
```

So is it a way to achieve this without raw statements?

For now I settled on the following solution:

```
MyOperations.objects.values('operation_start_time').annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(functions.Now() - F('operation_start_time'),
    output_field=DurationField()
)).filter(...)
```

It produces the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
 `myapp_myoperations`.`operation_start_time`,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, `myapp_myoperations`.`operation_start_time`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `time_spent`
FROM
 `myapp_myoperations`
WHERE ...
```

Or in the Python response object representation:

```
{'operation_start_time': datetime(...), 'diff': timedelta(...)}
```

Is it a way to get the response dict with only `diff` since this is the only field I am interested in?
Django ORM produced the query which requests `operation_start_time` just as we had written. But in case I remove the call to `values` at all it produces query which requests all table columns

**Solution** which produces the expected SQL

We should just put the call to `values` to the place in which `diff` is already known to the query

```
MyOperations.objects.annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(functions.Now() - F('operation_start_time'),
    output_field=DurationField()
)).values('diff').filter(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but I suggest you add an alias so you know what the result column will be called like `SELECT
 my_table.column_a + my_table.column_b as total .....`

Comment: @RiggsFolly so could you provide an example of Django code which will do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. You say if you remove the call to `values` is produces the wrong query, but what exactly is wrong? You actually **are querying** `diff` for every row on your table. You don't want that? And how does the first question in your description relate to the last question? First you ask if you can do column_a + column_b (and answer this yourself by showing how to use `F()` expressions), then you ask how to only get `diff` (which you also tell us by removing the `values()` call) and in the end you say you want something else but not what...

Comment: @dirkgroten removing the call to `values` will generate the SQL which selects all the columns. this is unnecessary data transfer from DB to the app. please take a look at the accepted answer or to the edit of the original question. I will put there the final solution which produces the expected query

Comment: Ok. Based on how your question was formulated I was expecting you knew what `values` does and already tried to add `values('diff')`. The call to `values('operation_start_time')` actually groups by that value meaning if two rows contain the same start time it would select only one of them.

Comment: yes. I've already known what `values` does but I just didn't try to put it after the call of `annotate` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values()` on your calculated field, so a query like

```
MyOperations.objects.values('operation_start_time').annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(functions.Now() - F('operation_start_time'),
    output_field=DurationField()
)).values('diff')
```

should give you a resulting queryset containing only your calculated 'diff'.

Comment: Great! that produced exactly the query I would expect. btw: we do not need even the first call of `values`. so I will put the final solution to the question itself since I failed to use the code formatting in the comment